# JavaScript Date timezone date before 1970 - 1906-01-02 working before that not working

Tags: javascript, datetime

i am using odata wcf data service , it returns date in format of /Date(millisecond)

i try to convert in time zone but i face issue with old dates

please check attached image difference

```
new Date(new Date('1906-01-02').getTime()-19800000)

new Date(new Date('1906-01-01').getTime()-19800000)

Tue Jan 02 1906 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) -- ok 

Sun Dec 31 1905 23:51:10 GMT+0521 (India Standard Time) --not good
```

it should be

```
Tue Jan 01 1906 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

[image: Image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: Spell JavaScript correctly to avoid search collision with Java.

Answer (score 2):

The values you're getting are probably correct.   Timezones aren't static throughout history:

> **It was not until 1905 that British India adopted standardized time zones.** The meridian passing east of Allahabad was picked as the central meridian for India. This came into force on 1st January 1906, though Kolkata and Mumbai maintained their own time zone until 1948 and 1955, respectively.  https://www.mapsofindia.com/on-this-day/1st-september-1947-indian-standard-time-is-introduced

...so your math is crossing over the boundary point at which that particular zone changed definition. (In general this sort of thing shouldn't be unexpected. Dates and times are a deceptively hard problem; the human calendar is irregular and not conducive to simple math.)